# Is it possible to create hard links to files in an iOS application bundle?

Tags: ios, iphone, symlink, nsfilemanager, hardlink

In order to save on server side bandwidth costs associated with my iOS application, I've packaged a bunch of assets that would otherwise be downloadable at runtime into my iOS application bundle. In the context of the application as written, it would be ideal for me if I could access the files from one of the user writeable directories (e.g. `[App Dir]/Library/Application Support/My Custom Subfolder/`) without having to copy the files there directly at runtime (e.g. at startup, first run, whatever).

While I've been able to successfully create symbolic links in `.../My Custom Subfolder/` to the files in the bundle using the `NSFileManager` API `createSymbolicLinkAtURL:withDestinationURL:error:`, some of the framework APIs I then use to access the content later on get goofed up and give me back attributes and data pertaining to the symbolic links instead of the underlying file. I could probably mitigate those issues by utilizing some other framework APIs but it might end up being a lot of work depending on the scope of the incorrect usages.

On the simulator I was able to successfully circumvent this issue by creating hard links to the bundle content using the `NSFileManager` API `linkItemAtURL:toURL:error:`. The hard links worked great for all the file access APIs utilized throughout the app and everything was peachy. On DEVICE however (tested on iPhone 5c running iOS 7.0.2 and iPad running iOS 7.1), I would receive an `NSCocoaErrorDomain 513 error (Operation could not be completed. Operation not permitted.)`. I could create a test file in `.../My Custom Subfolder/` and create a hard link to that in the same folder just fine, but if I try to hardlink to anything in the read-only application bundle, I get the 513 error.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get around the permissions error in order to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Like this: https://gist.github.com/albertodebortoli/2204433

Comment: @danh, thanks for your reply. However, your code snippet is simply copying the files into the user-writable directory, effectively doubling the amount of space the resource takes up on disk. My intention was to avoid copying the file and instead use a "hard link" to the file that would behave like the file without consuming additional disk space.

Comment: Why do you need hard links to the files in the app bundle instead of copying them? It sounds like you're trying to get around the prohibition on modifying the application bundle. If that were allowed, it would create a huge security hole.

Comment: @WilliamShakespeare In my case, I want to use hard links instead of copying the files out of the bundle, which is slower and uses extra disk space. I'm not trying to modify any of the files in the bundle; read-only is okay. I would use symbolic links (which I can create just fine, btw), but we've discovered bugs while playing videos through symbolic links.

Comment: To clarify in case @Naughty_Ottsel's non-reply gets deleted, I am using the default NSFileManager. I'm getting the path to the bundled file using [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] then adding the path to the file. I have checked that the path is correct and that I have read access to it. I'm getting the path to the sandbox file with ((NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES))[0] and creating a directory inside it, into which I'm trying to create the hard link.

Comment: @Michael Melanson Am I missing something? If you're not going to modify the files, why not just use them direct from the app bundle?

Comment: @CMLloyd This is getting off-track and into application-specific details. But suffice it to say that this is part of a larger system and the links are necessary.

Comment: I suspect you want the impossible.

Comment: Instead of copying or creating a hard link, you could move the data.

Comment: @HotLicks Perhaps I do. But keep in mind that I will also award the bounty to someone who provides "an authoritative explanation as to why this is not possible".

Comment: @gnasher729 Not possible, since the file I'm trying to link to is in the application bundle, which is read-only.

Answer (score 4):

You simply can't circumvent this error, I'm sure about that. I did not find any official docuentation - but several tutorials explaining how to allow the usage of symbolic links on jailbroken devices. There is no reason to me why the security on iOS is any different for hard links. In the simulator this works because it is operating on a path on your local machine (in ~/Library/Application Support/iphone Simulator/iOSVersion/Applications/...) and with local security. As an counter example, it occurred to me more than once that I had something working in the simulator that didn't work on the device and vice versa (for an example when trying to open a sqlite3 db in the main bundle with SQLITE_WRITE flag).

I resolve this resource management / versioning issue in my apps by using two different file locations. The original versions are inside the main bundle as usual. The other location is either the cache dir or the documents dir. Then I use a custom resource handler which returns a full path for a provided relative path. It works simply like so:

- If a relative path exists in the writeable dir, return this one. This is supposed to be an updated version of the requested relative file path
- If the previous check fails, look it up in the main bundle directory to return the original version from the app's main bundle

Some code (using the cache dir as the updateable directory, you may want to change that):

```
#define UpdateableCacheResourcePath(path) \
[[ResourceHandler sharedManager] updateableCacheResourcePath:path]

- (NSString*)updateableCacheResourcePath:(NSString *)path
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *_libraryCacheStorageDir = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] copy];
    NSString *updateablePath = [_libraryCacheStorageDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
    // Cache Dir
    if ([_fileManager fileExistsAtPath:updateablePath]) {
        return updateablePath;
    }

    // mainBundle
    NSString *mainbundleResourcePath = [_mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
    if ([_fileManager fileExistsAtPath:mainbundleResourcePath]) {
        return mainbundleResourcePath;
    }

    NSLog(@"File not found: %@", path);
    return nil;
}
```

In your code you would then use UpdateableCacheResourcePath("some.file") instead of looking in the main bundle. It also works with refrenced folders (drag drop folder to xcode and choose to create a reference instead of a group). Then you can reference relative paths with parent folders (like advertisements/adbanner.png).

The only drawback is that if you have web content you need to update all files that are referenced by your html site for obvious reasons (the web browser can only follow relative paths to the folder where the html document is inside).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it does not satisfy the criteria for the bounty since there's no solution and no explanation for why I can't create hard links. Symbolic links definitely work in this same setup (see the 4th comment on the question), but I cannot use them because there are bugs in video playback when used through symbolic links. I agree that there's no obvious reason why hard links should not also work, which is why I posted the bounty.

Comment: Thanks Michael Melanson for injecting some incentives to drive interest in this topic. @benjist, thanks for your suggestion. The workaround I opted for a few months ago around the time I posed this question is very similar to what you've suggested here. I gave in and paid the price of the hard-disk-footprint doubling for the convenience of a workable solution. Since other assets of the same category needed to be downloaded over the lifetime of the app, I was in need of building my own resource management system (read: custom bounded cache) anyway. Not ideal but it got 'er done.